# how to avoid scatter confirmation message?

Tags: eosjs, wallet, scatter

I have built an dapp EOS blockchain. It's almost like twitter where the user can tweet and also use as a microblogging site in EOS blockchain.I have used scatter as transaction signer for using my dapp. The real problem arises when I write something in my twitter a press post button it will ask the scatter permission to sign the transaction. My question is whether is it possible to avoid the scatter confirmation to make it user-friendly. my dapp : www.tweetblocks.com

Answer (score 1):

For the user, Scatter has "Enable Whitelist". You agree to the prompt, then check the boxes for the fields that are allowed to change. And then you are never asked again, unless you manually remove the whitelist entry.

Here is [an article](https://medium.com/getscatter/get-out-of-my-way-blockchain-7cd4383f4146) from Scatter author about whitelist permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Both scatter extension and scatter desktop are client side applications. End user is the only authority to decide whether scatter automatically sign the transaction without asking every time. If the user trust your contract then he/she can set the contract in whitelist so that, all signing request from the same contract will be done automatically without asking again and again.